# How on earth do I convert UML TO java?

Tags: java, uml

I've been asked to convert

[image]

Into UML, I get most of it it's just I don't know what to do on the lines of

+getemployees(): Employee and stuff where is says about +getManager(): Manager

Comment: *`How on earth do I do UML`* Jump higher and fly to the SKY

Comment: You have the UML, what do you want to do more?

Comment: Sorry I meant convert to JAVA

Comment: It's Java actually. Look for some converter (code generator) around. 
https://www.google.com/search?q=generate+java+from+uml+class+diagram&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#q=generate+java+code+from+uml+class+diagram&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official

Answer (score 0):

Although there are several tools allowing you to do the conversion automatically (for instance, Eclipse has tons of plugins enabling you to do that) I'd suggest you to try performing the conversion manually, at least once; it's very trivial, especially in this case. You just have to remember few things:

- you might want to map every UML entity (Employee, Contractor, Manager and Company) to a Java Class, so in this case your code will contain 4 classes
- every entity property maps to a Java property: for instance -name:String inside the Company entity is translated into something like: "there have to be a private String variable called name in the Company class"
- every entity method is also a method in Java

To sum everything up, here it is how the Company entity would appear:

```
class Company {
     private String name;
     private Employee[] employees;

     public String getName() { 
         return name;
     }
     public Employee[] getEmployees() {
         return employees[];
     }
}
```

As you might have noticed, there are few exceptions to the points I have listed: a relationship between two objects in facts has to be mapped to some methods and properties, in Java, but the UML model does not always list everything you need. In the particular case I shown you the UML model described the getEmployees() method, but not the employees property necessary to make it working.

In the case of the Employee class, you will have to add to the model both a method and a property, just to define the relation between Company and Employee:

```
 ...
 private Company company;
 public Company worksFor() {
      return company;
 }
 ...
```

I have found a tutorial on youtube that might help you to understand this a little bit more: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6wyk5BrgOFo